# ASP.Net MVC - Mandar datos de una vista a un controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

¿Cómo hago lo siguiente?

Tengo una vista clásica con tablas creada con razor de la siguiente manera:

```
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.a)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.b)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.c)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.d)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.e)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.f)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.g)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.h)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.i)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Listados", "listar", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
....
```

Claramente es una grilla, que por cada registro tiene 3 links, el primero que tiene el nombre de Listado va a la acción listar, ahora bien, la pregunta del millón es:

> Cuando hago clic en Listado, como hago para pasar la entidad seleccionada a la acción listar? y tambien como hago para pasar el valor de una de las columnas a la acción listar? obviamente también necesito saber como recupero el valor en la acción. Con preferencia que esta dato no pase por la URL.

Acción del controlador:

```
public ActionResult listar(string dato)
{
    CTPP oTar  = new CTPP ();
    oTar.strCodEmpresa = "1";
    oTar.strNroTarjeta = dato;
    oTar.datFechaIni = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016");
    oTar.datFechaFin = DateTime.Parse("12/12/2016");

    CLIS oLis = Servicioweb.listar(oTar);

    return View(oLis.lista);
}
```

O bien algo mas clave sería, en el mismo escenario de la grilla y los links, como paso un dato de la grilla como parámetro a una acción del controlador por medio de POST?

Comment: ¿Te fue útil alguna de las respuestas?¿Pudiste hacer funcionar tu código?

Answer (score 2):

Al hacer clic en **Listados** lo que deberias de hacer es pasar un código al método. Es decir

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Listados", "listar", new { id = item.ID })
```

Y luego, en tu método de controlador deberias de tener

```
    public ActionResult Listados(int id)
    {
        //Tu lógica aquí

        return View();
    }
```

Ahora, con respecto a tu petición de que ese valor no pase por la URL, no le veo ningún problema. Así trabaja ASP MVC. Normalmente las acciones de métodos de tipo GET se comportan de esta manera.

Por otra parte, no es recomendable pasar una entidad o un modelo por medio de un método GET. Lo ideal es enviar una llave, en este caso tu ID para luego identificarlo dentro del método

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo. [Microsoft - Examining the Edit Methods and Edit View](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)

Comment: En realidad es la primera opción que tome, pero cuando llega a la acción del controlador, el valor ID llega con valor null.

Comment: Hola, has probado en descomentar /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ y poner así la firma?  public ActionResult listar(string id)

Answer (score 0):

Los ActionLink envian los valores en la url. Para que no pase por url tendrás que hacer un servicio ajax y lo envias por medio de post hacia la función del controlador cs.

Te recomiendo que cambies tus ActionLink por botones. Que cada botón llame a una función que cree el objeto que contenga los valores que necesitas pasar al controlador cs. Aquí es donde entra el post de ajax.

Comment: Hola @Aaron. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar! Creo que esta respuesta podría beneficiarse enormemente con un ejemplo de código. La idea es sumar contenido con la mayor calidad posible en el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult listar(string dato)
{
    CTPP oTar  = new CTPP ();
    oTar.strCodEmpresa = "1";
    oTar.strNroTarjeta = dato;
    oTar.datFechaIni = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016");
    oTar.datFechaFin = DateTime.Parse("12/12/2016");

    CLIS oLis = Servicioweb.listar(oTar);

    return View(oLis.lista);
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más a qué te refieres con tu respuesta o qué diferencias existen con las otras respuestas?

Comment: Hola "hola", tu respuesta se reporto como de baja calidad, te sugiero leer [answer] que te brinda información para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. Hay que responder preguntas que sean creadas de acuerdo a [ask]. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.